# Im having trouble while serving or deploying Firebase Hosting Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin, firebase-tools

> The Cloud Functions emulator requires the module "firebase-admin" to
>   be installed. This package is in your package.json, but it's not
>   available. You probably need to run "npm install" in your functions
>   directory.

I was running well my project till i was hit with that issue. Any help, please do tell. Thanks. {Below is the image of what i am getting}

[image: I created a new project in the folder deletetest but it fails at first.]

Comment: "You probably need to run "npm install" in your functions directory."

Comment: I have run, deleted the npm-modules folder, and then run again but still gets the same message. It does not work at all.

Comment: you probably mean `node_modules`

Comment: yeah thats what I meant, and in the initialization process, the npm install had run well and installed all the packages.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue, it was working last week.

Comment: I have the same problem. Right now, i have to downgrade firebase-tools to version 6.8.0.

Comment: This one is working, I have downgraded to 6.9.0. And it has started working fine now. It deploys, for now. Let's hope the developers will update asap

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really the best place for this question.  Please post an issue on the GitHub repo.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: @Doug I did push the question to github issues.

Comment: They have resolved everything, I updated firebase-tools and installed npm package "firebase-functions-test": "0.1.6" in the devDependencies; then deployed and it worked

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug in `firebase-tools` versions `6.9.0` and `6.9.1`.  The solution is to downgrade to `6.8.0` for now:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@6.8.0
```

You can follow along with the issue here:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1262

Comment: They have updated, but the bug has now shifted. I hope they're testing this thing before even updating.

The Cloud Functions emulator requires the module "firebase-functions-test" to be installed as a development dependency. To fix this, run "npm install --save-dev firebase-functions-test" in your functions directory.
i  functions: Your functions could not be parsed due to an issue with your node_modules (see above)

Comment: They have resolved everything, I updated firebase-tools and installed npm package "firebase-functions-test": "0.1.6" in the devDependencies; then deployed and it worked