# Firebase Server complains that firebase-admin is installed but not seen

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin, firebase-tools

I tried running `firebase serve` on my local machine and gets below warning

> The Cloud Functions emulator requires the module "firebase-admin" to
>   be installed. This package is in your package.json, but it's not
>   available. You probably need to run "npm install" in your functions
>   directory.

**What I've tried from previous SO and github**

- npm install from folder functions
- delete node_modules and re-run npm install
- run npm install --save firebase-admin

**SO and github references but non solved my problem**

[The Cloud Functions emulator requires the module "firebase-admin" to be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56068579/the-cloud-functions-emulator-requires-the-module-firebase-admin-to-be-installe)

[Im having trouble while serving or deploying Firebase Hosting Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56056244/im-having-trouble-while-serving-or-deploying-firebase-hosting-functions)

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1452

PS:
Downgrade to version 6 is not an option.

I'm running node 8 and "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0" as shown from package.json

Comment: What is your exact version of Node.js? Make sure it is at least 8.13.0. The minor version number is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Hiranya Jayathilaka comment above I was able to fix this. I upgraded my node from 8.5.x to 8.16.2 and run `npm install firebase-tools` and everything works fine.